# How to integrate Gnome Contacts with Thunderbird?

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, 18.04, thunderbird, contacts

I have contacts in Gnome Contacts and I want to integrate/sync them with Thunderbird.

**How do I integrate Gnome Contacts with Thunderbird?**

---

**Note:** Due to the replies received, I should mention that **this issue is not related in any way with Google contacts but with Gnome contacts**.

Comment: Afraid I don't use either product but this might be a good starting place for your search: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/thunderbird/addon/gnome-integration/

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, this addon only allows you to configure notifications.

Answer (score 2):

A cloud workaround: I'm using Thunderbird 68.7.0 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 18.04, with the CardBook extension, version 43.9, to sync with a nextcloud provider. Since I've registered my nextcloud account in the system settings, Gnome Contacts allows me to sync with my nexcloud contacts as well. Synchronization isn't lightning fast, but for contacts, that's not a problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome Contacts is the GUI frontend that works with Evolution Data Server. You can perform more advanced tasks on contacts in Evolution and it will show up in Google Contacts.

Export the addressbook from Evolution

- To export a complete address book, click File ▸ Save Address Book As
  vCard.

Then import the addressbook in Thunderbird

- Click on Address Book click Tools ▸ Import and then choose the option address book and select the previously exported file.

Comment: you talking about Gnome Contacts right? as the GUI frontend to Evolution

Comment: Lincity,

Thanks for the information. I already know how sync Google Contacts but how can I sync Gnome Contacts?

I also already know how to import and export contacts. How can I sync/integrate them?

Comment: @Diogo Gomes ...You can't. It's not really a useful use case so nobody implemented it. If you want to sync then in the most cases its because you want it in different locations -> uses online e.g google contacts... If you work locally, you are expected to just decide on one tool to manage your contacts.

Comment: Thanks @FabianN. It's sad need to use Google.

I "de-googled" myself a long time ago and share my contacts information with Alphabet it's not an option for me.

Comment: Well you could at least find another online service. Just because you need some online service doesn't mean you need to use google...

Comment: Downvote because this answer is not about integration (i.e. use Gnome contacts and see all changes automatically also in Thunderbird) but about exporting from Evolution then importing to Thunderbird. Needs to be repeated all the time if you continue to edit contacts in Gnome Contacts.

Answer (score 0):

So I think that you can use this addon here to sync Thunderbird and Google, right? Follow the link: https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/thunderbird/addon/google-contacts/.

On this [link](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Set-up-email/Thunderbird-and-Gmail/ta-p/14181) of Mozilla support, you have more details between Thunderbird and Google (gmail, calendar and contacts).

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I already know how sync Google Contacts but how can I sync Gnome Contacts?